# IE9, how to reference window from the popup window opened from the opener, after the opener refreshed himself

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I know this is really a bizarre situation, but that's the truth.

I have a iframe in a page - **Frame-A**, I will open a popup window called **Win-B** from **Frame-A**, so, **Win-B** is the child of **Frame-A**.

```
win_b = window.open(...);
```

I can use **window.opener** in **Win-B** to call javascript within **Frame-A**, I can use **win_b.someFunciton()** in Frame-A to call javascript within **Win-B**.

Now, I refresh the page where **Frame-A** is in. **Frame-A** lost the reference to win_b, **Win-B** lost the reference of **window.opener**. However, I can still call javascript function in **Win-B** from **Frame-A** because I can do **window.open(..)** again on the same opened window to get the reference again. But I am not be able to call javascript function from **Win-B** to **Frame-A**, I can not restore the **window.opener**!

The question is how can I get back the reference the **window.opener** again. Basically, get the **Frame-A** reference in **Win-B**.

Comment: Wow - crazy. I have not tried it but being ballsy here. Can you pass a reference from a function in Frame-A to Win-B as a parameter `win_b.setCallback( callback );`, after you refreshed it an reestablished the refrence on the frame side.

Comment: @Mathias, make your comment an answer.

Comment: I am getting close, no sure how to send the reference of the frame to the popup window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really just guessing here and I haven't tested it but:
Can you pass a reference to a function in Frame-A from Frame-A to Win-B:

`win_b.setCallback( callback );` where `callback` is function in Frame-A

after you refreshed Frame-A and reestablished the reference to Win-B.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, made it working by simply passing the window reference to the popup window. Haven't thought about that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: cool. good to know that you can pass the window as a reference. I will remove my EDIT then.